# How to pass parameters from APEX to BI Publisher?

Tags: oracle-apex, bi-publisher

I have a BI report (excel), depending on the parameter (customer_id). I need to run it thousands of times with different values of this parameter. How can I run this report from the APEX cyclically changing this parameter?

Comment: Which version of oracle apex ?.Are you integrating BI publisher with oracle apex using web service reference?